# Joomla 3 test site vs. production site: which files should change?

Tags: joomla, web-deployment

I am maintaining a Joomla 3 site, and I want to set up a test site in a different web host, so that we can test code changes in it first. The test web host is in a different server, uses a different DB, etc., but otherwise I want it to be as identical as possible to the production site.

Which files should I pay attention to, when downloading and uploading the site to the other host? I know about **configuration.php**. Is there anything else?

(All the docs I've found when searching were about older versions of Joomla: 1.5, 2.x...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution which does not involve any third party component. You need to take care of some points though. Steps are explained below.

1. Copy the entire files from 1st server to 2nd server.
2. From phpmyadmin copy the database from 1st to 2nd server.
3. Change the database details and other configuration details in the configuration.php file. Mainly you need to change the database details and the log and tmp path. Check the log and tmp folders are writable.

   ```
   <?php
     class JConfig {
       public $db = 'joomla';
       public $dbprefix = 's5oiy_';
       public $log_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla/administrator/logs';
       public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
       public $memcache_server_port = '11211';
       public $password = 'dbpass';
       public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
       public $smtpauth = '0';
       public $smtphost = 'localhost';
       public $smtppass = '';
       public $smtpport = '25';
       public $smtpsecure = 'none';
       public $smtpuser = '';
       public $tmp_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla/tmp';
       public $user = 'root';
       public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
       public $memcached_server_port = '11211';
       public $redis_server_host = 'localhost';
       public $redis_server_port = '6379';
       public $redis_server_auth = '';
       public $redis_server_db = '0';
       public $proxy_enable = '0';
       public $proxy_host = '';
       public $proxy_port = '';
       public $proxy_user = '';
       public $proxy_pass = '';
       public $session_memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
       public $session_memcache_server_port = '11211';
       public $session_memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
       public $session_memcached_server_port = '11211';
   }
   ```

   ?>

These are the variables in configuration.php file that need to be checked once you change the server.

If you dont know the Base directory path you may give wrong log and tmp path. So to know the directory path you can use this code

```
<?php
$dir = getcwd();
echo $dir;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For things like this I suggest using Akeeba Backup and Kickstart

https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html
https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html

Just create a backup of your site and use Kickstart to install it on your test server. The install process will take care of the different settings. Make sure you disable sending mails from the test system. Otherwise your users might get mails the should not get.

Answer (score 1):

[Sven's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680552/sven-bluege) suggestion is great, here are a couple of other options.

There might be some advantages to creating your test site on the same server as your production site, for one thing, you'll know that the server environment will be the same.  Here are 2 ways you could do this.

You could create a new 'test' subdirectory on your production site and use Akeeba backup to install a copy of your site in that location. If you do this, take care to create a second test database and specify this new database when you use Akeeba backup. When you are finished your production site will be at www.domain.com and your test site will be at www.domain.com/test/

Alternatively [StageIt](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/stageit/) is a very good commercial plugin which will setup a staging environment on your production server. You can test your ideas and sync them back from the test to the production site when you are finished.

Good luck!